# Rake and current directory

Tags: ruby, rake

How do I get the directory where the rakefile.rb is located?

I want to use this as my root directory to locate everything off.

Comment: Have you considered the answer for Dir.pwd?  Seems more appropriate: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M002316

Comment: Dir.pwd gives you the directory, where you are in, when launching the rake command. This is not necessarily the place of the rakefile.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

use `__FILE__` to get the file name then you can get the directory from there:

in `test.rb`

```
puts __FILE__
```

output:

```
/users/foo/test.rb
```

`__FILE__` resolves to the full path of the file it is in.

Use this to get the dir name:

```
File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Comment: This is mostly right, but is wrong in the case where the Rakefile requires some other file and that file needs to know the location of the Rakefile; in that case `Rake.application.original_dir` is what you want.

Answer (score 24):

You can get it by calling **application.original_dir** method. In task you can achieve *application* object using **application** method on task object.

Comment: I don't think this addresses OP's question, but it's the answer _I_ was looking for. :)

Comment: in the later version of Rake I have this is Rake.original_dir

Comment: original_dir seems to return the dir you were in when you ran rake, not the dir containing the Rakefile.  I just checked the docs and wrote some test code and cannot find a way to determine that...

Comment: You can see in the method raw_load_rakefile that the location is assigned to a location variable, displayed to STDOUT, then thrown away; there's no way to retrieve it.  :(  (https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/application.rb#L674)

Comment: Update: You can call the method that raw_load_rakefile itself calls (find_rakefile_location) to perform the recursive Rakefile search again and get the location returned to you.  Still can't believe this value hasn't been turned into an attribute...

Comment: Confirming another comment above (and put another way_) -> this doesn't work if you you run the rake command from somewhere other than the root dir.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use Dir.pwd

?

Comment: The problem with that is that you might invoke the rakefile from some other directory like: $rake -f subdir/rakefile      and you may want the path where the rakefile exists because you may need other dependencies available there.  Using Dir.pwd would give you the current working dir but that wouldn't be where your other dependencies live (say you've got jar files, for example)

Answer (score 4):

As of Ruby 2 you can use [`__dir__` instead of `File.dirname(__FILE__)`](https://bogdanvlviv.com/posts/ruby/with-__dir__-we-can-restore-order-in-the-universe.html) to get the directory that contains the current script.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a RoR app your Rakefile.rb should be in your RAILS_ROOT directory.  So in any script you can specify file location like

```
 config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/extras )
```